# Remove index.php from middle of URL, wordpress on linux

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, .htaccess

I've tried this code so far:

```
AddType x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But i can't work out what i'm doing wrong with it. The URL does rewrite if i go to url.com/index.php it will change to url.com/ . But if i go to url.com/index.php/sample the url will not rewrite. I think i'm missing a wildcard off the end, but i can't work out what the code is doing at all so it's hard to tweak. I've tried looking on SE, but can't find anything that actually works for linux/wordpress combo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this problem is solved in different way. Follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Go to `wp-admin`

**Step 2:** Open Settings > Permalinks

**Step 3:** Check `Post Name` Option and Save

you are done now. Check the URL now.

Comment: Awesome, worked a charm. Needn't have been altering the .htaccess file afterall!